# Why my ASP.NET Core C# Application automatically logout after 10 to 15 min?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.0

I have made a C# Asp.net Core application it's working fine. But problem is that it will automatically logout user after 10 to 20 minutes or after one operation is over then automatically user logout from the system.

I am using Azure database.

Comment: Define logout? Do you store the "i am logged in" thing in a session - read up on session expiration.

Answer (score 1):

Most login schemes on .NET CORE use CookieAuthentication somehow. Most likely your problem lies there.
If you check out the documentation about cookie authentication, you'll see that you can set a timespan for which the cookie should be valid.

[cookie options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie#controlling-cookie-options)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
});
```

Should fix your problem.

You can also make it "sliding", that means your cookie will get extended when half of the timespan has passed and the user makes a new request.